# local copy of my drupal site doesn't seem to link

Tags: 7

I isntalled a local LAMP system and basically copied my site into `/var/www/` for some local "experiments" (without messing around with the live site). I've mirrored the db and everything. Now when I go to `http://127.0.0.1/` my home page is loaded well but all the links (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/content/lodge`) won't load, I just get **404 Not Found**. I assume I'm missing some kind of php or apache setting.

**edit1**

I did

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

but this didn't seem to have made a change at all.
Now within `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` I have two files `000-default.conf, default-ssl.conf`. 
`000-default.conf` contains:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and `default-ssl.conf` contains

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost    
DocumentRoot /var/www
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

and I'm not exactly sre where to add `AllowOverride All`, can you be a little more specific?

Oh and `.htaccess` is in `/var/www/` too

**edit 2**

okay, now what I did, I installed a fresh copy of drupal in `http://127.0.0.1/alternatives/Quaaout/` and if I use the original site folder with a new db, urls like `http://127.0.0.1/alternatives/Quaaout/?q=user` work just fine! But if I use my `site/` directory from the live site, this url automatically leads me to a `404` at page `http://127.0.0.1/alternatives/Quaaout/user` and the difference makes which `database` I have setup in my `settings.php` - with the new db from the fresh copy, `?q=user` works fine, with the live copy it doesn't. So I thought it may be the `url redirections` I have setup in table `redirect` but I cleared it and it still didn't work.  So it's not the redirections, what else would be causing this?

Comment: You probably have to set Clean url https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls (link like 127.0.0.1/q=user works?)

Comment: Have you checked that `http://127.0.0.1/?q=content/lodge` is working fine?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Yes but that doesn't work either, I don't know what's going on exactly here... :o

Comment: @arrubiu I followed that guide, thanks but it didn't solve the issue as `127.0.0.1/q=user` doesn't work for me either...

Comment: Please check your `.htaccess` file and settings for _RewriteBase_. I also found this type of error when I setup local site from live server. I need to comment _RewriteBase_ in `.htaccess` file. You also need to check _clean url_ setting in admin of the site to verify _mod_rewrite_ is working fine in your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a copy of a working vhost file (000-default.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure apache has mod_rewrite enabled, and that the drupal .htaccess file is there in your drupal root. If you're on debian/ubuntu, you should be able to do:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: You may also have to go to /etc/apache2/sites-available and edit the virtual hosts there. The directory entries should contain [AllowOverride All] (without the brackets). Restart apache to make changes take effect.

Comment: See my answer below (needed to add new answer to allow code)